# How is it possible to select the text at the back of the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image in the front and a text at the back. I want to make the text selectable while the image still being in the front. How can I achieve this ?
Link to jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/G5BeU/

Sample code

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">@media print {  .gmnoprint {    display:none  }}@media screen {  .gmnoscreen {    display:none  }}</style>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Custom StreetView</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
#parent-street-view{position:relative}
#map_canvas{position:absolute !important;width: 500px; height: 400px; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);z-index:0}
#parent-street-view .overlay-pollution{width: 500px; height: 400px;position:absolute;z-index:100; }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent-street-view">
        <div id="map_canvas" >This is supposed to be visible and selectable</div>
        <img class="overlay-pollution" src="http://www.mickeys.net/assets/images/default/transparent.png" />
    </div>

    <!--<canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px" style="position:absolute;top:500px;"></canvas>-->
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple, set the `pointer-events` CSS property of the image to `none`. This will allow you to select the text behind.

You might also want to lower the opacity on the image, so you can partially see the text.

```
#parent-street-view .overlay-pollution {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.5;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/G5BeU/2/

Answer (score 3):

Use this code.

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">@media print {  .gmnoprint {    display:none  }}@media screen {  .gmnoscreen {    display:none  }}</style>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Custom StreetView</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
#parent-street-view{position:relative}
#map_canvas{position:absolute !important;width: 500px; height: 400px; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);z-index:0}
#parent-street-view .overlay-pollution{width: 500px; height: 400px;position:absolute;z-index:100; }

.overlay-pollution:hover + #map_canvas , #map_canvas:hover
{
    z-index: 1000;
}

</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent-street-view">
        <img class="overlay-pollution" src="http://www.mickeys.net/assets/images/default/transparent.png" />
        <div id="map_canvas" >This is supposed to be visible and selectable</div>
    </div>

    <!--<canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px" style="position:absolute;top:500px;"></canvas>-->
</body></html>
```

**Note :**

Style added

```
.overlay-pollution:hover + #map_canvas , #map_canvas:hover
{
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

HTML code tag change places

```
<img class="overlay-pollution" src="http://www.mickeys.net/assets/images/default/transparent.png" />
<div id="map_canvas" >This is supposed to be visible and selectable</div>
```

See this example at http://jsfiddle.net/Ct2X8/1